# How can I use the posted ID to get data from 2 different database tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, post

I have created two different tables called diner and gebruikers.
From diner I want to display gerecht, capaciteit en prijs and from gebruikers I want to display voornaam, woonplaats, straatnaam, huisnummer and email. I have a common id, in the diner table it is called gebruikersid and in the gebruikers table it is just called id.

```
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{



  $adres =  $row['adres'];
  $woonplaats = $row['woonplaats'];
  $voornaam = $row['voornaam'];
  $email = $row['email']; 


  echo "<ul>";
    echo "<h3> Eetprofiel van " .$row['voornaam'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Woonplaats: " .$row['woonplaats']. "</li>";
    echo "<li> Adres: " .$row['straatnaam']. " " .$row['huisnummer']. "</li>";
    echo "<li> Meld je aan door een mailtje te sturen naar " .$row['email'].  "</li>";
echo "</ul>"; 
}

  $gebruikersid = $_POST['id'];
  $sql2 = 'SELECT gerecht, capaciteit, 
               prijs
        FROM diner WHERE gebruikersid = '$gebruikersid' '; 



mysql_select_db('nassen_database');
$retval2 = mysql_query( $sql2, $conn );
if(! $retval2 )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{



  $gerecht =  $row['gerecht'];
  $capaciteit = $row['capaciteit'];
  $prijs = $row['prijs']; 


 echo "<ul>";
    echo "<h3> Op het menu staat " .$row['gerecht'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Capaciteit: " .$row['capaciteit']. " personen</li>";
    echo "<li> Het kost " .$row['prijs']. " credits </li>";

echo "</ul>"; 
}
```

The first query works and gets the right results, but I think there is a mistake in the $gebruikersid=$_POST['id']. The posted ID is from the other database table, so that might be a problem? If i just fill in WHERE gebruikersid = '27' in the second select statement it does work.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Edit: This is what both database tables look like:

[This is the diner database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsPhK.jpg)
[This is the gebruikers database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InSmJ.jpg)

id in the gebruikers database is the gebruikersid in the diner database. So the user with id 26 (in gebruikers database) added pizza to the diner database.

Comment: Please add a representation of the database tables and some sample data.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I have added it. Would be great if you could help me out!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, It was flagged for review, so I was just reviewing it